# Oracle SQL Between Date, Except Some Month

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I've got a query which basically    get information concerning the last 2 years from the current Date.

```
DateTime jodaCurrentDate = new DateTime();
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm");
String startingDate = formatter.print(jodaCurrentDate.minusYears(2));
String endingDate = formatter.print(jodaCurrentDate);   

"DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE (\'"+ startingDate +"\',\'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI\') AND " +
    "TO_DATE (\'"+ endingDate +"\',\'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI\')";
```

Is it possible to retrieve only for some particular months (01-02-03-10-11-12) for example?

Comment: show some dummy data

Comment: I really hope that you're using bind variables in your actual code rather than building up SQL statements with string literals.  That's going to kill performance in addition to being a vector for SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This where clause filters for a date between two dates and also includes a filter on month.  Replace some_date with your date column.

```
where some_date between to_date('01/01/2015','MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('12/31/2015','MM/DD/YYYY')
and extract(month from some_date) in (1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12);
```